# PDFBox convertToImage not rendering some PDFs correctly

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox's PDPage.convertToImage() method to convert pages of a loaded PDF file into images. It works fine for some PDFs however it gives me errors to the console for a lot of files which then don't render correctly on the screen - images and text are missing.

```
Dec 31, 2013 7:15:34 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: EI
Dec 31, 2013 7:15:34 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont getawtFont
INFO: Using font SansSerif.plain instead

Dec 31, 2013 7:02:15 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
INFO: unsupported/disabled operation: i
```

The file load is done simply using:

```
PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(file);
List<PDPage> pages = pdfDoc.getContent().getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
PDPage page = pages.get(pageNo);
page.convertToImage();
```

I tried using loadNonSeq() instead of load() but that didn't help. Is there something I should be doing with the PDFStreamEngine to allow it to process these PDFs? I'm not sure if the reader can't actually render these or if the functionality needs enabling somehow.

Comment: EI means the end of an inline image. That might explain missing images. The font replacement means that some font is not available or cannot be read.  This might amount to missing text. Details can probably be told after you supplied a sample PDF.

Comment: In addition: `i` defines the curve flattening tolerance, so that's hardly a critical issue here. Weird: the error suggest `BI` seems implemented but `EI` is not -- unless your PDF is malformed! For common (European..) text, a replacement font should not lead to missing text.

Comment: I've uploaded a file here which doesn't render properly: https://mega.co.nz/#!GNdVzYID!JhwU8U2Y96T2C1rQR2JdPxPbU2sxjXpzgKi1jlGclvI

Comment: All I get is some of the lines surrounding the text and the headers, no text whatsoever is rendered.

Comment: @LadyRacheya Unfortunately you did not add a notification tag to your comment, so I had not seen your file before today. That been said, I just converted your PDF to image using `page.convertToImage()` but only got the *unsupported/disabled operation: i* info, not the other ones, and the images look as expected. Thus, it might be an issue of either your PDFBox version (I'm testing with trunk, i.e. a 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT which should be virtually identical to 1.8.4 in this respect) or the runtime environment (jdk 1.7, *not headless*, in a MS Windows environment).

Comment: @mkl That's strange, there's just no text for me although I am only getting the unsupported/disabled operation: i info. I'm using PDFBox 1.8.3 as I simply downloaded the latest jar I could find, and the same setup (jdk 1.7, windows ect).

Comment: You say you *downloaded* the latest jar. That makes me assume you do *not* use maven for automatic loading of required additional libraries. Thus, you have to add the [dependencies](http://pdfbox.apache.org/dependencies.html) manually. So, have you included the fontbox and jempbox components in your class path?

Comment: @mkl I haven't been using Maven. I didn't have the correct jar files but after adding them into the classpath it still isn't working. I'm going to keep looking into it though.

Comment: The glyphs don't display with the released version (1.8.7) but they do display with the non-released version (2.0.0) that you can get with svn. The released versions can't display certain type1 fonts :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your problem solved in my previously answered post, By using `PDFRender jar` it is possible.

[How to increase the resolution of image in PDF renderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21064270/1624035).

The posted **Question** converts only first page of PDF and **Answer** converts all pages of PDF into image format.

Answer (score 0):

try fontbox jar from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/fontbox/1.8.5

or use maven repository..