# DIsplay converted pdf in android webview offline

Tags: android, pdf, webview, offline

Do you have any ideas how to display converted pdf into html in webview properly? There are some problems with scalling when i put converted html directly, mostly with document width. I don't want to manipulate html code if it's not nescesarry, becouse converted file is big and ugly. Scalling may be the option, but ad max width text is barely visable. I know i could display pdf, but i try to make app work offline.
Do you have any ideas how to do that properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean "Display a Local PDF File in a WebView"

this link help you to do that

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question directly but you could give a try to this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html

The pdf renderer does not require html nor a web view, that's why i don't think it will suit your answer, but it does provides zoom (as it is displayed in a image view) and high quality display if you follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32327174/4664754