# How to show content (course such as Mathematics) in android like "bac 2016" (digischool app)

Tags: java, android, pdf, document

I have an android application and I show courses (Mathematics,Physics,History and so on...).

I use android pdfView by [Yoan Zapata](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview) using pdf documents but its not show as good,clear even in zooming, professional as digischool apps course content show.

How can I show my courses content like  [bac 2016](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kreactive.digischool.bac) or `brevet 2016` apps by digischool.
This is exemple of cours in digischool app
[image: This is digischool app cours]

[image: This is exemple in my application]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem exactly ? Is the PDF low quality ? If so you can solve this by following this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32327174/4664754 wich basically explains you how to scale your rendering depending on the screen resolution of your device.

Here is the code presented in the link, but i highly recommand you to check directly the link as it is very well explained

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi/72*mCurrentPage.getWidth() , 
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi/72*mCurrentPage.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: I have edit my question with screenshot. My problem is that in my app,the content is not as good as 'bac 2016' one. I do not know if it is the problem of the librairy I use or if I have to check for another one or look for payed librairy.

Comment: Well i don't understand what you are trying to say. We have to speak in english on this site but i feel like you will be better understandable in your native language. Donc quel est votre problème précisément ? Parce que "ça apparait pas aussi bien que sur l'appli de untel" ça ne veut pas dire grand chose. Est-ce que le pdf manque netteté ? Et surtout est-ce qu'il ne serait pas plus simple et plus intéressant pour vous de faire votre propre lecteur pdf plutôt que d'utiliser des librairies que vous ne comprenez pas bien ?

Comment: Mon problème est la netteté des cours dans l'application. Parfois certains cours sont flou d'autres le sont quand on zoom. Donc en gros, c'est la netteté de mes pdf et donc mes cours dans l'application qui est mon problème. C'est pourquoi j'aimerais savoir s'il y a un meilleur moyen d'afficher mes contenus (mes cours) pour avoir une clarté aussi net que l'application bac 2016 de digischool. Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse. Et aussi faire mon propre lecteur pdf sera peut -être beaucoup très complexe. Merci infiniment. @Yan yankelevich